# What would be the range of a cargo 777 full of usable fuel up to MTOW?

Tags: airliner, fuel-consumption, range

Having read about [Rutan's Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_Voyager) and more recently about [Virgin Atlantic GlobalFlyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Atlantic_GlobalFlyer)
I wondered how would some modern long haul airliner such as a cargo Boeing777 (or other airliner) perform at this specific longest range flight attempt?

Assuming take off at MTOW, and carrying as a payload no passengers but only
usable fuel (tanks in cabin connected to existing fuel lines) and pilots.

What would roughly be the achievable range and/or how would one proceed to estimate this range?

Comment: Several years ago, I chatted with a pilot who'd recently qualified on the 777. He spoke very highly of it, saying that the only problem with the airplane is that "it can hold ***way*** too much gas."  The scenario given here would elevate that objection to a higher dimension!  Interesting question nevertheless.

Comment: Flying slower will improve range. How much so is moot. || I tried to enthusiastically ask CGPT4 to provide an order of increase with decreasing speed. It utterly failed to do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, go to the [Boeing Airport Planning documents](https://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/plan_manuals.page) website.  This includes a wealth of information about most Boeing commercial aircraft.  Choose the document that matches the aircraft you're interested in.  I'll choose the 777F document because you mentioned a cargo 777.

Scroll through to PDF page 45.  That is a payload-range diagram for the aircraft.
[image: 777F Payload Range Diagram]

This chart shows the aircraft's capabilities in terms of payload, range, and fuel.  The X-axis represents the range.  The Y axis represents the amount of payload in terms of OEW (operational empty weight) plus Payload.  OEW is used because different airlines outfit their aircraft in slightly different ways, so their starting point (OEW) is different.  The 777F's OEW is about 318000lb.

The horizontal line across the top of the payload-range diagram depicts the maximum zero fuel weight (MZFW).  This is typically a structural limit for maximum landing weight.  You can't land heavier than this without risking breaking the gear.

The first corner of the payload-range diagram represents the maximum gross weight at brake release.  In this case, 766,000 lb.  I.e. 448,000 lb of payload and fuel.  The upper-left corner of this line is the maximum payload choice for that gross weight -- 229000 lb payload, 219000 fuel.

Following along that line, we remove a pound of payload and replace it with a pound of fuel (to maintain constant brake release gross weight).  As we do this, the aircraft can reach longer range -- same weight, but more fuel.  This continues until the fuel tanks are full.  I.e. we reach the second corner on the chart-- 320860 lb fuel.

At that point, we can continue reducing the payload to increase range -- but since we can't add more fuel, we don't get as much of a benefit.

If you wanted to add more fuel tanks in the cargo bays of the 777F, you could do so.  The empty tanks would add to the OEW.  So instead of starting from 318,000 you might start a few thousand pounds heavier.

To estimate the best achievable range, you want to extrapolate the line from the first corner on the payload-range diagram (the one at constant brake release gross weight).  Extrapolate that line out down and to the right until  you reach the OEW of your modified aircraft with more tanks.  Performing highly accurate eyeball extrapolation, I estimate 13,000 nautical miles.

The slope (m) of this corner of the payload-range diagram represents an important fundamental aircraft performance quantity.  We just have to invert it and change the sign...

The slope is (very approximately)

$m=rise / run = -100000 lb / 3000 nm$

$m=-\frac{1}{SR}$

or

$SR=-\frac{1}{m}$

Where $SR$ is the specific range of the aircraft.  So about 30nm/1000lb fuel.  This is a measure of fuel efficiency similar to MPG for a car.

If you look at the term in the front of the Breguet Range Equation, I think you will see the Specific Range there.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but doesn't this chart/answer depend on a weight limit FOR LANDING which we could/probably would ignore for a situation like this?

Comment: MZFW isn't about landing; your max landing weight limitation covers those concerns. Max zero fuel weight is *essentially* a "max fuselage weight" for the case that the wing tanks are mostly empty and you have the greatest bending moment on the wings. That bending, not the gear, is what MZFW protects: even flying short hops (minimal fuel required), you can't necessarily load iron weights into the fuselage right up to max landing weight. More an issue on some planes than others.

Comment: @MikeB There are many constraints that limit the performance of an aircraft.  This diagram tries to depict them all.  The only one that has anything to do with landing is the horizontal line across the top.  On this aircraft it is MZFW -- on some aircraft is is Maximum Landing Weight.  It always represents the maximum payload possible.  Rest assured, the chart summarizes a full mission.

Comment: thanks for this very good explanation of such a chart, i guess 13,000 nm is already amazing, shouldn't the extrapolated part of the curve vary its slope since it drops "payload" while flying, (at some point in flight)?

Comment: @jkztd: That was my thought, too, that fuel-per-mile decreases as the plane gets lighter, so there are diminishing returns to adding more fuel.  Not nearly as bad as in rocketry where the amount of extra fuel per delta-V grows exponentially (Tsiolkovsky's rocket equation).  It looks to me like the interior lines in the diagram aren't perfectly straight, e.g. the 575 (261) line has a steeper downward slope on the top left than the bottom right.  I think that makes sense: for the same takeoff weight, if more of it is fuel, the end of your flight will be with a lighter plane, better efficiency.

Comment: @jkztd: Holding up a straight edge to my monitor, even the farthest right line we're extrapolating is slightly concave, so it is better.  The curve would be more pronounced if much more of the total weight were fuel.  (I'm not sure of the empty dry weight of the plane, but the "crew+payload" axis tells us the max for that with zero fuel = zero range is 547 thousand lb.  And that's about 1.7x as much fuel as the normal 320,800 lb.  Maybe even a bit more since burning the fuselage fuel before the wing-tank fuel will avoid the wing-loading fuselage-weight problem Ralph J pointed out.)

Comment: Yes, that corner is concave.  If you print it out and sight along the line, you'll see the curvature.  The specific range of the aircraft varies in flight.  The slope of this line represents an average over the entire mission.  All of these missions (along that line) start at the same gross weight -- but they end at different gross weights, so the average changes.

Comment: The other thing that is relevant -- aircraft range beyond about 11000 nautical miles is pretty useless (it is half the circumference of the earth).  If you have to go further than that, you go the other way to get there...  Obviously, Voyager and Global Flyer had a reason to exceed this limit.

Comment: @PeterCordes The tyranny of the rocket equation applies to **any** situation where you're hauling any form of supply that lowers your performance (which means most situations.)  It's always exponential, it's just that in most situations you're in the very bottom part of the curve where the climb is very small.  Rocketry is farther up the curve than anything else I'm aware of humans doing routinely but it's the same curve.  It's just a modern jet has an ISP in the ballpark of 3,000 whereas hydrolox is about 450.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Besides I_sp, there's also the lift-to-drag ratio, since a plane's thrust just has to overcome drag while the wings balance gravity, vs. a rocket's thrust acting directly on its full weight.  But yes, L/D ratio is also just a linear factor (and it doesn't change much with weight, or does it?), so the extra fuel per distance is still exponential.  Extra fuel per delta-V is exponential, but distance and delta-V are different.  Thrust required to overcome drag drops as the plane gets lighter, but delta-V is thrust times current mass... I *think* fuel vs. distance is exponential.

Comment: Your analogy to the rocket equation isn't that useful.  Rockets get all their thrust by accelerating the fuel.  Jets get most of their thrust by accelerating the air (by using the energy in the fuel).  Likewise, the rocket equation ignores the drag, aircraft performance is all about drag.  There is a logarithm in the range equation, ln(W_i/W_f).  That is the cause of the slight curvature.

Comment: @RobMcDonald Just because it's taking in oxygen rather than bringing it along doesn't make ISP not meaningful.  Same as an ion engine collecting solar power doesn't negate the concept of ISP.  It's just airplanes operate an awful lot lower on the curve than big rockets.

Comment: @LorenPechtel You're missing the point about the air. Think about battery-electric propeller powered aircraft vs. a bottle of compressed air. The bottle of compressed air is like a rocket. It mixes fuel and oxidizer (the propellants) and accelerates them aft to produce thrust forward -- the thrust is mdot Vj. All propellants are carried on board, when you're out, you're out. The other system uses the energy in the battery to turn a prop to accelerate the ambient air aft. The thrust is still mdot deltaV. The difference is, the propellant (air) is not carried on board -- you can't run out.

Comment: The rocket eqn also applies for brief instants in time to produce a deltaV of the mass.  After an initial acceleration, aircraft fly for a long period of time at constant velocity. With a rocket in space, you make a large change to the kinetic and potential energy of the vehicle. With an aircraft, all the energy goes to waste heat due to drag -- the aircraft typically starts and ends its mission at sea level and zero velocity (no useful work done). Yes you can calculate Isp for a Jet or a Propeller.  Yes it is large.  No, it is not very useful for intuition for aircraft performance problems.

Comment: @RobMcDonald Sure, it doesn't produce the same acceleration because there's ongoing drag losses.  Rockets also suffer drag loss on the way up and truly huge drag "loss" on the way back down.  ISP is simply a measure of how much push you get per unit of fuel, independent of things like drag, using supplies from the environment etc.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I'm more taking issue to the analogy to the rocket equation.  The rocket equation applies an impulse for a very short time to achieve a deltaV -- and then the mass coasts under the influence of gravity and drag.  Aircraft performance is not like that at all.  One of the consequences of the rocket equation is that (if the rocket is initially at rest) the center of mass of the rocket and propellant stays at rest at the same location.  In order to send a rocket to the moon, you have to send equal propellant the opposite direction.  Air breathing propulsion is not like that at all.

Answer (score 8):

First cut numbers, working from [Wikipedia's B-777 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777), and using the 777-200LR, since that seems to be the longest-ranged of the models:

- Max Takeoff Weight (aircraft + passengers + cargo + fuel) = 766,000 lbs
- Operating empty weight (just the aircraft & crew) = 320,000 lbs
- Max Fuel, conventionally configured: 321,000 lbs (approximately)
- Leaves non-fuel weight available, with full tanks, of 125,000 lbs (i.e. 766 - 320 - 321 = 125)

So that's how much ***more*** fuel weight you could carry in the new tanks without the aircraft being overweight.  Which is less than half-again the existing fuel load, so we aren't going to be getting dramatic 3X increases in range.

The published range for the 777-200LR is 8,555 NM, which is stated as almost enough to connect any possible pair of airports in the world.  Multiplying that times the ratio of notional fuel capacity to existing fuel capacity (i.e. 446,000 / 321,000) gives a result of 11,886 NM.  Not near Voyager's 26,366 NM flight.

Disclaimers:

This leaves out a ***lot*** of factors.  How much OEW you lose by stripping out seating, galleys, and so forth, and how much you add by adding fuel tanks & pumps, is one.

Also, the distance you fly per pound of fuel when an airplane is full of gas and heavy, is significantly less than the distance you fly on a pound of fuel in a light aircraft.  So while the 8,555 nm range figure is presumably starting at a max-weight takeoff (the same as the notional flight), it ends heavier than the hypothetical flight -- so the "extra" gas effectively gets used more efficiently, since it's used when the aircraft is lighter than it would be in revenue service. (This dynamic is captured in Rob McDonald's answer, and his 13,000 NM range seems like about the right increase here.)

Also, the published range builds in some worst case, or 90% worst case assumptions about winds and reserves -- if you say you can fly from X to Y, you also want to be able to fly from Y to X, even when the winds are strong (i.e. a headwind on one of the two legs).  If you're planning a record-setting flight, you just fly *with* the winds, and where they're best for you.  And you'll spend the additional last hours of your flight at a maximally efficient (high) altitude because you're so light.  Which probably is where you'd enjoy strong tailwinds as well.  So all of that would improve on the number above by quite a bit, since you're not trying to fly in both directions between your two airports routinely, but only once when conditions are best.

Nevertheless, unless you get waivers for a far higher takeoff weight than what's published (which the performance on a cold day at Edwards AFB would probably support), you're still far, far short of being able to do what Voyager did.

Comment: Setting aside for a moment the specific question on this page, as a non-aviator I had absolutely no idea, did not realize, the fuel in an airliner when you "top it off" is roughly the same as the airliner!!!

Comment: There's a reason those two planes look like they do. They're essentially gliders that don't depend on thermals.

Comment: @Fattie: The amount of fuel in a modern airliner is crazy. A SpaceX Falcon 9 rocket has roughly the same fuel capacity as a Boeing 747. It takes several large tank trucks to refuel a single one of them. Kind of puts into perspective how much fossil fuel we burn every day, because thousands of big planes fly all around the globe every day and yet aviation only contributes ~3% of the world’s CO2 emissions.

Comment: @JörgWMittag what differientiate those three is mostly flight speed i think, the airliner is some sort of a glider too, meant to fly much faster

Comment: @RalphJ this helps a lot also regarding altitudes and speeds thanks, i like the idea of an aerosucre like take off and out of fuel landing, also this should be validated both directions, jetstreaming is cheating except for aerostats

Comment: You commented on Rob's answer that MZFW is also about wing loading from fuselage weight with wing tanks empty.  Keeping the wing tanks full until after you've burned some of that fuselage fuel away would change that, perhaps by some factor of the weight the wing tanks can hold, like maybe 0.5 or 0.25?  So we could be looking at another 100,000 pounds of fuselage fuel?  Unless you bump into another limit like gear limits or MTOW even at Edwards AFB.  (I presume you'd need special certification to *legally* do this; I'm just talking about physics and engineering, not regulatory.)

Comment: Max ***zero fuel*** weight is just that, so as long as you plan to burn the fuel in the fuselage (rather than landing with it) (or burning it **after** you've burned the fuel in the wing tanks - which you wouldn't reasonably do), then it doesn't count against your MZFW. The relevant limit for this exercise is MTOW. Increasing that (via waiver, engineering, whatever) will increase your range. The ZFW limitation is the least of the concerns, since the ***only*** thing you're carrying above OEW **is** fuel.

Comment: @RalphJ: Didn't see your reply since you didn't @ notify me.  I wondered if the limiting factor for MTOW on the spec sheet for the standard config involved max fuselage weight + max wing fuel, rather than engine performance and tire speed, etc.  Since the normal config has all the tanks in the wings, right? So MZFW on the spec sheet is about fuselage weight, and I said MZFW to refer to that spec, even though in this case we're putting fuel in the fuselage.  Oh, I googled and found there's a center tank that has more than half the total capacity, so nevermind.

Comment: What engineering and safety factors do set the MTOW limit?  Would a long runway on a cold day with higher weight be approximately as safe as rated MTOW on a shorter runway in less ideal conditions?  I guess that's a separate question I should post if it isn't a duplicate.  I'm guessing factors like brake heating, since rejecting a takeoff with higher speeds and more weight means significantly more kinetic energy.

Comment: @PeterCordes I suspect that it would be *lots* of engineering analysis to raise the MTOW. What could get approved for a one-time record attempt, no passengers, new brakes, miles of runway, etc could probably be lots higher than what they'd get (or try for) for regular commercial service. So could they get it raised? My hunch is, yes, by a good bit. Enough to approach 3X the published range? Doubtful.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I was indeed thinking in terms of a one-time good-conditions MTOW for a range record attempt, with willingness to put more wear and tear on components and the airframe than would be acceptable for routine use, but trying to avoid undue risk to the life of the pilots.  I wasn't expecting anywhere near 3X published ranged either; 777 is such a different plane from the record-holders that it's not a meaningful goal.  It's just fun to play what-if and optimize a hypothetical max-range 777 flight, as per the question.  Max loiter time is also interesting.